# Java JFrame frame.dispose() not working as expected

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to dispose of my frame and create a new one. The new one gets created but the old one persists. I end up having two frames on my desktop. What am I missing? Thanks.

```
package org.rockislandschools;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DisplayStatus extends JFrame {

    public void buildFrame(String ipAdd, String status){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Host Status");
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JLabel ipLabel = new JLabel(ipAdd);
    ipLabel.setOpaque(true);
    ipLabel.setBackground(Color.white);
    ipLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 25));

    JLabel stateLabel = new JLabel(status);
    stateLabel.setOpaque(true);
    if (status.equals("Up")){
        stateLabel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
    if (status.equals("Down")){
        stateLabel.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    stateLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 25));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(ipLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(stateLabel, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}


package org.rockislandschools;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class HostStatus {

    public String IsReachableReturnString(String ip){

        String canBeReachedReturnString = "Down";
        int timeout = 10000;

        try {
            if (InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(timeout)) canBeReachedReturnString = "Up";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return canBeReachedReturnString;
    }

    public boolean IsReachable(String ip){

        boolean canBeReached = false;
        int timeout = 10000;
        try {
            if (InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(timeout)) canBeReached = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println(canBeReached);
        return canBeReached;
    }

}

package org.rockislandschools;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(args.length == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Please specify IP Address.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String address = args[0];

        HostStatus status = new HostStatus();

        String currentState = status.IsReachableReturnString(address);

        DisplayStatus statusFrame = new DisplayStatus();

        statusFrame.buildFrame(address, currentState);

        //String newState = status.IsReachableReturnString(address);

        while (true){
        String newState = status.IsReachableReturnString(address);
        if (newState.equals(currentState)){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("Nothing has changed");

        }
            else {
            statusFrame.setVisible(false);
            statusFrame.dispose();
            System.out.println("Building a new frame");
            currentState = newState;
            statusFrame.buildFrame(address, currentState);
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

I am not sure what I need in regards to more details. I can tell you that I am just starting with attempting to learn Java. I live in Iowa and like to spend my free time not being hassled by red arrow boxes that criticize my posts.

Comment: Needs more code, this won't compile.  However, Swing is not thread safe, you have to [use the Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).  I don't see that here so that may be an issue.

Comment: Here is the rest of the code... https://github.com/mpmackenna/HostStatus/tree/master/src/org/rockislandschools

Comment: @mpmackenna please don't post external links. Copy and paste your code **here** in StackOverflow.

Comment: @Frakcool I am having trouble doing that. I have three classes and whenever I copy and paste the content gets jumbled. I tried indenting and adding backticks. I continue to get the following error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted" etc. Is there another way or do you have have to hand edit every block of code to make it display right?

Comment: *"do you have have to hand edit every block of code to make it display right?"* If by that you mean *'select the entire code block in the input form (including the final `}`), then click the `{}` button above it',* then ..yes.  But where does the 'editing' come into it?

Comment: I don't know; it kept telling me I needed to edit it again. I got it to work by using sed as indicated in this suggestion. This guy apparently had the same issue. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168446/how-can-i-add-four-spaces-before-each-lines-of-programs-code-in-terminal

Comment: If you want the frame to disappear from view, call `setVisible(false)` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you were calling statusFrame.dispose(); you were calling that on a JFrame that did not exist. I fixed the code and here are each of the files:

> **EDIT:**  I have a version of this with system tray and GUI for selecting the IP on my github: https://github.com/ArgonBird18/HostStatus

**Main.java**

```
package org.rockislandschools;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(args.length == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Please specify IP Address.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String address = args[0];

        HostStatus status = new HostStatus();

        String currentState = status.IsReachableReturnString(address);

        JFrame statusFrame = new JFrame();

        statusFrame = DisplayStatus.buildFrame(address, currentState);

        //String newState = status.IsReachableReturnString(address);

        while (true){
            String newState = status.IsReachableReturnString(address);
            if (newState.equals(currentState)){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                System.out.println("Nothing has changed, Time is " + timeStamp );

            } else {
                //statusFrame.setVisible(false);
                statusFrame.dispose();
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                System.out.println("Building a new frame, Time is " + timeStamp);
                currentState = newState;
                statusFrame = DisplayStatus.buildFrame(address, currentState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HostStatus.java**

```
package org.rockislandschools;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class HostStatus {

    public String IsReachableReturnString(String ip){

        String canBeReachedReturnString = "Down";
        int timeout = 10000;

        try {
            if (InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(timeout)) canBeReachedReturnString = "Up";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return canBeReachedReturnString;
    }

    public boolean IsReachable(String ip){

        boolean canBeReached = false;
        int timeout = 10000;
        try {
            if (InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(timeout)) canBeReached = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println(canBeReached);
        return canBeReached;
    }

}
```

**DisplayStatus.java**

```
package org.rockislandschools;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DisplayStatus {

    public static JFrame buildFrame(String ipAdd, String status){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Host Status");
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JLabel ipLabel = new JLabel(ipAdd);
        ipLabel.setOpaque(true);
        ipLabel.setBackground(Color.white);
        ipLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 25));

        JLabel stateLabel = new JLabel(status);
        stateLabel.setOpaque(true);
        if (status.equals("Up")){
            stateLabel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        if (status.equals("Down")){
            stateLabel.setBackground(Color.red);
        }   
        stateLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 25));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ipLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(stateLabel, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;

    }

    public static void editFrame(JFrame frame,String status,String ipAdd){
        frame.setContentPane(new JPanel());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JLabel ipLabel = new JLabel(ipAdd);
        ipLabel.setOpaque(true);
        ipLabel.setBackground(Color.white);
        ipLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 25));

        JLabel stateLabel = new JLabel(status);
        stateLabel.setOpaque(true);
        if (status.equals("Up")){
            stateLabel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        if (status.equals("Down")){
            stateLabel.setBackground(Color.red);
        }   
        stateLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 25));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ipLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(stateLabel, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
    }

}
```

Good luck with your host status program!

Comment: Thanks so much. Totally above and beyond my expectations. I really appreciate the help.